# How does one say “What do you mean?” in Esperanto?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I’ve seen (in the romaneto “Gerda malaperis”):

> Kion vi volas diri?

However, I suppose that just like in English, there is a slight difference between ***“What do you mean?”*** and ***“What do you want to say?”***. The former asks about the meaning of that which the speaker said, while the latter (though it may also have the same meaning) may be understood as ***“Please change your way of expression because I didn’t understand what you said.”***

I find the same distinction made in Bulgarian: ***„Какво имаш предвид?“*** and ***„Какво искаш да кажеш?“***

So, how can one say that in Esperanto? Does ***“Kion vi signifas?”*** convey the same meaning or this won’t work?

Or am I being too picky and there is no difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A usual expression is

> Kion vi celas?

More precise would be "*Kion vi celas **diri**?*" but you'd drop "diri" in colloquial language.

Comment: That's interesting. I instinctively thought of "Kion vi celas?", but couldn't justify the meaning using vortaro.net

Comment: A common alternative to "Kion vi celas?" is "Kion vi intencas?".

Comment: These common expressions aside, this answer doesn't quite get to the question of how do you say "mean" as in "intend to say." The answer to that is indeed "voli diri."

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, *Kion vi volas diri* means both, though you can be more specific if you like. You can't say *Kion vi signifas* in this sense.

That's the tl;dr, now for the longer answer.

### The meaning of mean / La signifo de signifi

According to the freely-available [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mean_1?q=Mean), the first two meanings of the verb **mean** are:

> 1. Have as meaning
> 2. Intend as meaning

Whereas [vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/#signifi) has

> 1. Havi precize difinitan sencon

But nothing to correspond to 2. So in any case "Kion vi signifas" is not possible in the meaning you require.

### *Mean* and *want to say*

As you've said in your question, "mean" and "want to say" can mean the same thing, so **Kion vi volas diri** is fine for both. If you really want to specify, "What do you mean?" as opposed to "What do you want to say", you could say for example:

- **Kion tio signifas?** (Focussing on the meaning, not the person)
- **Kion vi intencas diri?** (More literal gloss of 2. above)
- **Kion vi celas [diri]?** (With apologies to Johmue.)

Answer (score 3):

***Kion vi signifas?*** is wrong. **Signifi** means "to have a certain meaning". Words, signs, symbols, etc. have meanings, but people don't: they have intentions.

I wouldn't say that *"Kion vi volas diri?"* expresses that you didn't understand, but it perhaps does have the implication that the person didn't say what they meant, and invites them to change the meaning, rather than express it in a different way. I think *"Kion vi vol**is** diri?"* says what you want.

Comment: I realised that ***“Kion vi signifas?”*** is wrong moments after I posted the question but decided to not edit it for self punishment. :)

Comment: I think it's a useful thing to leave in your question, as I certainly found it confusing myself when I first wanted to say "What do you mean?" in Esperanto.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in English, *his meaning* means "intended significance" and *its meaning* usually means "literal significance". The former is translated *celo*, "aim" (or, to avoid ambiguity, you might make that *dircelo*) and the latter is *signifo* (or pedantically, *denotacio*).

"What were you just trying to say?"

> *Kion vi ĵus celis diri?*
>
> *Kion vi ĵus dircelis?*

"What is the meaning of what you just said?"

> *Kion tio signifas?*
>
> *Kio estas la signifo de (tio) (kion vi ĵus diris)?*