# Kiel oni diras "I mean..." en Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Tia vorto ofte mankas al mi, kiam mi volas ion specifi aŭ korekti. Ekzemple:

> – Ĉu vi vidis tiun krokodilon?
>
> – Krokodilon?? Ne estas bestoĝardeno ĉi tie!
>
> – Ne, [**I mean**] tiun ulon, kiu parolis al siaj amikoj en la [*enigi lingvon*].

Kutime mi povas diri "mi volis diri", sed ĉu estas pli taŭga esprimo por ĝi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, I would say *mi volas diri* or *mi celas* and so I'm inclined to think this is a duplicate of this question.

[How does one say “What do you mean?” in Esperanto?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/295/how-does-one-say-what-do-you-mean-in-esperanto/311#311)

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, and the answers there show good equivalents in both formal and informal contexts. Thank you and sorry for posting a duplicate question!

Comment: Nothing to apologize for. No problem.